# How do I detect a query returned no rows in golang?

Tags: go, rows

I wrote a very simple database query function in golang. The pseudocode is like this:

```
    var ctx = context.Background()
    conn, _ := sql.Open("firebirdsql", "SYSDBA:masterkey@localhost/"+BdLocation)
    defer conn.Close()
    rows, err := conn.QueryContext(ctx,"<sql query>")
    // my first attempt was to detect empty result here
    switch {
    case err == sql.ErrNoRows:
        < empty result logic >
        rows.Close()
        return 
    case err != nil:
        log.Fatal(err)      
    }
    defer rows.Close()
    // very 'primitive' logic, the only one that worked
    var count int = 0 
    for rows.Next() {
        < process row >
        count ++
    }
    // tried do get empty result here also
    if err := rows.Err(); err != nil {
       if err == sql.ErrNoRows {
          log.Println("Zero rows found")
       } else {
          panic(err)
       }
    }
    // this worked
    if count == 0 {
         < empty result logic >
    } else{
         < return result for processing >
    }
```

Compilation is ok, and it works, but only because I used the "count" variable as a flag. I think I'm following the documentation (and examples) correctly, but err is always nil, even with an empty result. Just as a test I inserted syntax errors in the query, and they were detected.
Am I missing something? Or it just does not work the way I think it does?
Thanks for your help.

Comment: If you expect at most one row, then call QueryRow and check for sql.ErrNoRows.  Otherwise, you must count the rows as in the second half of the question.  The sql package does not return an error for an empty query results because empty results are valid.

Comment: Thanks! I'll stick to my solution, then, although i think it's not elegant. Curiously, I found an exemple of sql.ErrNoRows used with QueryContext at https://github.com/cockroachdb/examples-go/blob/master/photos/db.go, and I assumed it was possible to do that.

Answer (score 1):

You can check for a `sql.ErrNoRows` (https://golang.org/pkg/database/sql/#pkg-variables)

BUT as you are using a firebird sql driver... It could be another error.

We assume that all drivers implements and returns what was specified by golang... But that could not be true.

Check the actual error and verify it on the Firebird driver.

Comment: Thank you. I'll search for possible differences in the firebirdsql driver.